# To validate the $ \exists x [E(x) \land C(x)]$

Tags: logic, quantifiers

Show the validity of

(1) $\forall x [M(x) \implies C(x)]$

(2) $\exists x[M(x) \land H(x)]$

(3) $\forall x [E(x) \implies H(x)]$

so, (4)  $ \exists x [E(x) \land C(x)]$

============================================

I try to simply  them to

(5) $M(c) \implies C(c) $             ............. ui

(6) $M(c) \land H(c) $                   ...............ei

(7) $E(c) \implies H(c)$    .........ui

(8) $C(c) \land H(c)$  ..........(4) & (5)

now I am stuck on step 8. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advanced!!

Comment: Are you sure you have (3) written down correctly? Because (3) holds even if there is no $x$ such that $E(x)$, in which case (4) cannot possibly hold. Should you have $E$ and $H$ trade places in (3)?

Comment: about (3), the statement is "All the students who are good at English also work hard", E(x) = "x is good at English" and H(x) = "x works hard"

Comment: I second user43208's objection, which I don't think your comment addresses.

Comment: To make user43208's comment more explicit: (4) is not a consequence of (1), (2), and (3), because of the following counterexample: The domain of discourse consists of a single element, which satisfies $M$, $H$, and $C$ but not $E$.

Answer (score 3):

The argument would be valid if you had, for the third premise:

$$(3)\;\;\forall x\,(H(x) \rightarrow E(x))$$

Otherwise, one cannot validly derive the desired conclusion.

This is what things would look like with the third premise as posted here:

(1) $\forall x [M(x) \implies C(x)]$

(2) $\exists x[M(x) \land H(x)]$

(3) $\forall x [H(x) \implies E(x)]$

(5) $M(c) \implies C(c) $             ............. ui

(6) $M(c) \land H(c) $                   ...............ei (c)

(7) $H(c) \implies E(c)$    .........ui

(8) $M(c)$ ........ (6) simplification ($\land$ - Elimination)

(9) $H(c)$ .........(6) simplification ($\land$ - Elimination)

(10) $C(c)$ .......(5, 8) modus ponens

(11) $E(c)$ .......(7, 9) modus ponens

(12) $C(c) \land H(c)$  ..........(10, 11) $\land$ - Introduction

Now we are justified in using existential introduction:

(13) $\exists x\,[C(x) \land H(x)]$.

Comment: Nice job showing those steps with justification +1